# Problema ao realizar bind de delegate no ninject

Tags: asp.net, ninject, ioc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com ninject para IoC e entity framework, mas quando realizo o bind com delegate ele dá esse erro:

```
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Error activating IntPtr No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable. Activation path: 5) Injection of dependency IntPtr into parameter method of constructor of type Func{EventStoreDbContext{Pedido}} 4) Injection of dependency Func{EventStoreDbContext{Pedido}} into parameter contextFactory of constructor of type SqlEventSourcedRepository{Pedido} 3) Injection of dependency IEventSourcedRepository{Pedido} into parameter repository of constructor of type PedidoApplicationService 2) Injection of dependency IPedidoApplicationService into parameter pedidoApplicationService of constructor of type HomeController 1) Request for HomeController Suggestions: 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IntPtr. 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel. 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel. 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name. 5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
</ExceptionMessage>
```

A implementação do repositório:

```
public class SqlEventSourcedRepository<T> : IEventSourcedRepository<T> where T : class, IEventSourced
    {
        protected static readonly string sourceType = typeof(T).Name;
        protected readonly Func<EventStoreDbContext<T>> contextFactory;
        protected readonly ITextSerializer serializer;
        //private readonly IEventBus eventBus;
        private readonly Func<Guid, IEnumerable<IVersionedEvent>, T> entityFactory;


        public SqlEventSourcedRepository(ITextSerializer serializer, Func<EventStoreDbContext<T>> contextFactory)
        {
            //this.eventBus = eventBus;
            this.contextFactory = contextFactory;
            this.serializer = serializer;

            // TODO: could be replaced with a compiled lambda
            var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(Guid), typeof(IEnumerable<IVersionedEvent>) });
            if (constructor == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Type T must have a constructor with the following signature: .ctor(Guid, IEnumerable<IVersionedEvent>)");
            }

            this.entityFactory = (id, events) => (T)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { id, events });
        }

        public T Find(Guid id)
        {
            using (var context = this.contextFactory.Invoke())
            {
                var deserialized = context.Set<Event>()
                    .Where(x => x.AggregateId == id && x.AggregateType == sourceType)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Version)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(this.Deserialize)
                    .AsCachedAnyEnumerable();

                if (deserialized.Any())
                {
                    return entityFactory.Invoke(id, deserialized);
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

        public T Get(Guid id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Save(T eventSourced, string correlationId)
        {
            var events = eventSourced.Events.ToArray();
            using (var context = this.contextFactory.Invoke())
            {
                var contextSet = context.Set<Event>();
                foreach (var e in events)
                {
                    contextSet.Add(this.Serialize(e, correlationId));
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            //this.eventBus.Publish(events.Select(e => new Envelope<IEvent>(e) { CorrelationId = correlationId }));
        }

        private Event Serialize(IVersionedEvent e, string correlationId)
        {
            Event serialized;
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                this.serializer.Serialize(writer, e);
                serialized = new Event
                {
                    AggregateId = e.SourceId,
                    AggregateType = sourceType,
                    Version = e.Version,
                    Payload = writer.ToString(),
                    CorrelationId = correlationId
                };

                return serialized;
            }
        }

        private IVersionedEvent Deserialize(Event @event)
        {
            using (var reader = new StringReader(@event.Payload))
            {
                return (IVersionedEvent)this.serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
```

A classe que estou utilizando com o módulo do ninject(que não consigo realizar o bind do "EventStoreDbContext<>" que no construtor da implementação do repositório o recebe como "Func>", e não consigo passar com o código

```
Bind(typeof(EventStoreDbContext<>)).ToSelf();
```

):

```
public class Module : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ITextSerializer>().To<JsonTextSerializer>();

            Bind(typeof(EventStoreDbContext<>)).ToSelf().InTransientScope().WithConstructorArgument("EventStore");

            Bind<IMessageSender>().To<MessageSender>()
                .WithConstructorArgument("name", "schema")
                .WithConstructorArgument("tableName", "tabela");

            Bind<IDbConnectionFactory>().ToConstant<IDbConnectionFactory>(Database.DefaultConnectionFactory);

            Bind<IEventBus>().To<EventBus>();
            Bind<ICommandBus>().To<CommandBus>();

            Bind<IPedidoApplicationService>().To<PedidoApplicationService>();

            Bind(typeof(IEventSourcedRepository<>)).To(typeof(SqlEventSourcedRepository<>));
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Você tirou ele daqui](https://github.com/mspnp/cqrs-journey)?

Comment: A parte do repositório do event sourced sim.

Comment: Bom, não conheço bem Ninject, mas o erro diz que isto aqui não funciona: `Bind(typeof(EventStoreDbContext<>)).ToSelf().InTransientScope().WithConstructorArgument("EventStore");`. O *Bind* deveria ser um `Func<>`, não de um `Type`.

Comment: Então, o ninject não permite que eu passe essa função
  Bind(typeof(Func<EventStoreDbContext<>>)).ToSelf().InTransientScope().WithConstructor‌​Argument("EventStore");

como 
  Bind(typeof(Func<EventStoreDbContext<>>)).ToSelf().InTransientScope().WithConstructor‌​Argument("EventStore");

Dando um erro que precisa passar algum tipo no  EventStoreDbContext<>, sendo que eu precisaria de um bind genérico pra funcionar corretamente(quando não é uma classe genérica ele permite fazer isso).

Comment: Então, [acho que não rola passar o `EventStoreDbContext<>` assim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243632/how-to-bind-generic-type-interfaces-in-ninject). Eu passaria pelo menos com a interface como argumento genérico.

Comment: Você diz realizar o bind assim:      `Bind(typeof<IEventStoreDbContextM<>>).To(typeof<EventStoreDbContext<>>)`

?

Eu tentei assim também e não deu certo. Estou pensando em mudar para outro injetor, talvez seja mais fácil ou realize esse bind sem mais problemas.

Comment: Não. Assim: `Bind(typeof<IEventStoreDbContextM<IEntidade>>).To(typeof<EventStoreDbContext<IEntidade>>)`.

Comment: Mudei de injetor e utilizei o Unity e funcionou, obrigado de qualquer maneira!

Comment: Poderia por favor colocar uma resposta para a comunidade entender o que você fez para solucionar seu problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi esse problema mudando o injetor do `ninject` para o `unity` e ele conseguiu resolver essa dependência.

Answer (score 0):

A classe EventStoreDbContext tem um parametro de tipo? se não tente algo assim:

```
Bind<EventStoreDbContext>().ToSelf().InTransientScope().WithConstructorArgument("EventStore");
```

Comment: A classe EventStoreDbContext é genérica mas não possui restrições de parâmetros de tipo, mas não é permitido implementar a linha de código sem o "<>" no EventStoreDbContext, ou seja, tem que especificar o genérico(ex.: `IEventStoreDbContext<Pedido>`) ou passar como genérico(ex.:`typeof<IEventStoreDbContext<>>`).